# How to access dynamically generated div elements value in JQuery on click next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

How to access dynamically generated div elements value in JQuery on click next and previous button.

We are creating dynamic div that contains the question ID, Question text and question options. And on click next and previous button we displayed the one question at a time from that dynamically generated div by using jQuery.

**Now I want to access current question id from the current div into the jQuery on click next button.**

Please share simple example on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    })
 .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();       
      var questionPaperDetailsIdjsp     =$("#questionPaperDetailsId").val(); // This not working .
      alert(questionPaperDetailsIdjsp);// This not working .

      });
    
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="divs">
            <%
                ArrayList listQuestionOptions = new ArrayList<String>();    
                int QID = 0;
                AssessmentVO allQuestions = (AssessmentVO) request.getAttribute("stuassessmentVO");
                int Slength = allQuestions.getSections().size();
                for (int j = 0; j < Slength; j++) {                 
                    List<QuestionVO> Qlength = allQuestions.getSections().get(j).getQuestions();
                    for (QuestionVO e : Qlength) {
                        QID++;
                        int NextQuestionId=Qlength.indexOf(e.getId())+1;                    
                        int Olength = e.getOptions().size();
                        for (int i= 0; i < Olength; i++) {
                        listQuestionOptions.add(e.getOptions().get(i).getOption());
                    }   
                    %>
                    <div id="div1" class="div1 div2"> <br><%=e.getQuestionBaseType()%><br><%= QID +e.getDescription()+listQuestionOptions%>
                    <input type="hidden" name="questionPaperDetailsId" id="questionPaperDetailsId" value="<%=e.getId()%>"> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="tag<%=QID%>" value="<%=e.getId()%>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="NextQuestionId" id="NextQuestionId" value="<%=NextQuestionId%>"> 
                    </div>
                    <%
                    listQuestionOptions.removeAll(listQuestionOptions);
                        }                   
                } 
                %>
</div>

<a id="next" class="btn btn-success">Next</a>
<a id="prev" class="btn btn-warning">Prev</a>
```

Comment: First if `questionPaperDetailsId` is the id of a div, then `.val()` will not work, since `div` dont have value, try with `.text()`. Second, it would be helpful if you could provide your html

Comment: `$("#questionPaperDetailsId").val()` makes it look like you have multiple elements with the same `id=` - which is not allowed so jquery always picks the first one.  **Update:** your HTML generation confirms this.

Comment: As it's a hidden input: `$(".divs div:visible [name=questionPaperDetailsId]").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to  show value of previous div input you can use `$(".divs div:visible").prev('div').find("[name=questionPaperDetailsId]")` this will find div which is currently visible then use `prev` to get previous div reference finally use `find` to access your inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divs div:not(:first)").hide() //hide all divs not first
  $("#next").click(function() {
      if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
      else {
        $(".divs div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs div:first").show();
      }
      return false;
    })
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //check if prev length is > 0  (show prev div value : else show current div value)
      var questionPaperDetailsIdjsp = $(".divs div:visible").prev('div').length > 0 ? $(".divs div:visible").prev('div').find("[name=questionPaperDetailsId]").val() : $(".divs div:last").find("[name=questionPaperDetailsId]").val()
      console.log("value =" + questionPaperDetailsIdjsp);
    });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $(".divs div:visible").hide();
      $(".divs div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">

  <div class="div1 div2"> <br> Soemthing
    <br> Options :
    <input type="hidden" name="questionPaperDetailsId" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="tag1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="NextQuestionId" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="div1 div2"> <br> Soemthing2
    <br> Options :
    <input type="hidden" name="questionPaperDetailsId" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" id="tag2" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="NextQuestionId" value="3">
  </div>
  <div class="div1 div2"> <br> Soemthing3
    <br> Options :
    <input type="hidden" name="questionPaperDetailsId" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="tag3" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="NextQuestionId" value="4">
  </div>

</div>

<a id="next" class="btn btn-success">Next</a>
<a id="prev" class="btn btn-warning">Prev</a>
```